# Create a batch file to invoke testng.xml to run selenium scripts

Tags: selenium, batch-file, testng

I need help to create a `.bat` file to invoke `testng.xml` which has all the tests to run.According to this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/testng-users/MwHAox2g538), I created the `.bat` file. Here is what I have written in it:

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\Selenium Execution Engine\lib\library\testng-5.8-jdk15.jar";"C:\POM_Newdemo\EF_Progression\bin\testscripts" org.testng.TestNG "C:\POM_Newdemo\EF_Progression\testng.xml"
```

where:

- `-cp` : is class path
- `C:\Program Files\Selenium Execution Engine\lib\library\testng-5.8-jdk15.jar` :  is the path of my testng jar file
- `C:\POM_Newdemo\EF_Progression\bin\testscripts` : is the path of my .class files of my tests
- `C:\POM_Newdemo\EF_Progression\testng.xml` : is the path of my `testng.xml` file

It is throwing error as follows:

```
[Parser] Running:
  C:\POM_Newdemo\EF_Progression\testng.xml


Suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0


[ERROR]:
Cannot find class in classpath: testscripts.Test_Demo
```

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. If it does not work provide the full path of test.xml file.Please do let me know if it worked

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\Selenium Execution Engine\lib\library\testng-5.8-jdk15.jar":C:\POM_Newdemo\EF_Progression\src\testscripts" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1| Copy any one of the below methods in a text file
2| Save it as yourtext.bat
3| Open the batch file created to run the test.
```

Method **#1**

```
cd C:\Workspace\projectname
java -cp C:\Workspace\projectname\lib\*;C:\Workspace\projectname\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Method **#2**

```
cd C:\Workspace\projectname
set ProjectPath=C:\Workspace\projectname
echo %ProjectPath%
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\lib\*
echo %classpath%
java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\testng.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve by using surefire plugin in your maven project

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
  <configuration>
   <suiteXmlFiles>
    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> *if the testng.xml is in different folder then pom.xml please include the path*
   </suiteXmlFiles>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Once you configured the testng.xml create a batch file with below text

```
cd C:\workspace\projectdir (the folder where pom.xml is available)
mvn test
```

All done! :)

Answer (score 0):

The last

cd C:\workspace\projectdir (the folder where pom.xml is available)
mvn test

is ultimate